# Rules for cascading macros in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I cannot find rules for C preprocessor that handle the case below. If you assume a straight substitution this case should not even compile because `a=--1`. But if you assume substitution with parenthesis then `a=-(-1) = 1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  ALPHA -1
#define  BETA -ALPHA
int main(void) {
    int a = BETA;
    int b = -ALPHA; // this compiles too, why? b = --1
    printf("%d\n",a); // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do yourself a favour. Use macros as little as possible - they are not type safe. They are simple text substitutions, Use the power of the compiler

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessing is the phase which precede compilation it generates a preprocessing translation unit which will be the input for compiler.

Some of those steps in its process are (*From* ***C99 5.1.1.2***):

> 3. The source file is **decomposed** into **preprocessing tokens**. (...)
> 4. Preprocessing directives are executed, **macro invocations are expanded**, (...)

As you can see Tokenization **precede** macro invocation so `-ALPHA` will be considered as 2 **separate** preprocessing tokens (*i.e.  `-` and `ALPHA`<sup>1</sup>) and not as you thought by 2 preprocessing token `--1` ( `--` and `1` )

After that in rule 7:

> 7. **White-space** characters **separating tokens** are no **longer significant**.
>      Each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

So the compiler will get tokens and ignore whitespaces.

If you generate the preprocessing file with `gcc -E` whitespaces have no significance and those you are seeing are only for formatting to user and cannot reflect the real internal behavior of CPP.

From ***[GCC CPP 5.4.0 1.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html)***:

> **Tokens do not have to be separated by white space**, but it is often
>   necessary **to avoid ambiguities** (...)
>
> Once the input file is broken into tokens, the **token boundaries never
>   change**, except when the ‘##’ preprocessing operator is used to paste
>   tokens together
>
> The **compiler does not re-tokenize the preprocessor’s output**. Each
>   preprocessing token becomes one compiler token.

Summarizing:

If you write `-ALPHA` => tokens are:

- `-` punctuator - binary minus sign
- `-` punctuator - binary minus sign
- `1` constant - integer constant

If you write `--1` => tokens are:

- `--` punctuator - Decrement operator
- `1` constant  - integer constant

Decrement operator should not be used with constant that's why you get error in this case during compilation.

---

<sub>1 : `ALPHA` identifier will **be replaced** (in phase 4) by two preprocessing tokens `-` and `1` **already identified** in macro definition</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This is how your program looks after pre-processing is completed.

```
int main(void) {
    int a = - -1;
    int b = - -1;
    printf("%d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

You can view this output using `-E` option with `gcc`.

It is definitely not `--1`. Notice the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to understand that C Preprocessors is not a part of compilation process. It's just the substitution process which tells the compiler to do required pre-processing before the actual compilation.

To understand much you have to read the [Macro Pitfalls](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Pitfalls.html).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.